MS Surface Laptop and Displaymatrix
I have a LED screen connected to a displaymatrix. If the device have a built-in HDMI port, everything is fine. If we put the HDMI in a usb-c dongle, then it would not conncect.
I have tried various devices, inluding iPad, MS Surface Studio nothing works.
Any idea would be helpful.

Not all USB C ports support display output.
